# Save Pages Shortcuts For All Documents

Tags: pages, shortcut

In Pages you can set shortcuts for the different type of fonts:

[image]

But it only saves the shortcut for that one document. Does anyone know of any way to save the shortcuts for all documents?

(I've looked in Pages preferences)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although it is not possible to change for ALL documents, you can create a custom template that preserves the shortcuts for future documents based on that template.

1. Set your shortcuts in a new document, preferably one you already have formatted the way you like it.
2. Click **File** > **Save as Template...**
3. Save in **Template chooser** and name the Template.
4. Use this new template (Found under **My Templates** whenever you wish to use those particular shortcuts.

Of course, this will only preserve the shortcuts for that particular template and all documents based on it, not universally with other documents.

[image: Menu Save as Template]

[image: Dialog - Save template]